# How to find an object's 3D coordinates (triangulation) given two images and camera positions/orientations

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration, triangulation, stereo-3d

I am given
Camera intrinsics: focal length of the pinhole camera in pixels, resolution of the camera in pixels
Camera extrinsics: 3D coordinates (X,Y,Z) of 2 points where pictures of the object were taken, heading of the camera in both positions (rotation, in degrees, from the y axis - the camera is level with the x-y plane) and camera pixel coordinates of the object in each image.

I am not given the rotation and translation matrices for the camera (I have tried figuring these out but I'm confused on how to do so without knowing translation of specific points in the camera frame to 3D coordinate frame).

PS: this is theoretical so I am not able to use OpenCV, etc.
I tried following the process described in this post: [How to triangulate a point in 3D space, given coordinate points in 2 image and extrinsic values of the camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55740284/how-to-triangulate-a-point-in-3d-space-given-coordinate-points-in-2-image-and-e) 
but do not have access to the translation and rotation matrices which all sources I've looked at used.

Comment: Hey crs123 - This question reads a bit like "Do my homework". You'll likely get a more thorough answer if you include steps you may have tried, what tools you have available or what you're trying to accomplish. While I'm not qualified to answer, this looks pretty math heavy, you might want to give a math specific overflow site a try.

Comment: added a few details to the original question and will post to the math stack exchange as well